# Xamarin Forms does not recieve firebase notification send from php

Tags: php, firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am Working on Xamarin Forms Platform to Implement the Firebase Notification. I have add google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist in android and IOS applicaition respectively by setting appropriate property.I have generated token code natively and using dependency service I am getting the generated token for sending notification on same or different device. For sending the Notification I am using php since my application use php as mediator for communicating with database and xamarin forms.

```
class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService, IPushHelper
{  
 public string GetPushToken()
 {

     return FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
 }   
}
```

```
 public interface IPushHelper
  {
        string GetPushToken();
 }
```

This is how I am Accessing Token in Xamarin Forms

```
string token = DependencyService.Get<IPushHelper>().GetPushToken();
```

PHP Code For Sending Notification

```
 $fields = array(
                'to'  => $token // Token Generated By Xamarin Forms
                'data'=>  array("message"=>$message) // Message For Notification
                );
//Header Including API Key
$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization:key='.$api_key
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Also, I have tried shell_exec() for running curl

```
 $result =shell_exec('curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key='.$api_key.'" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"'.$token.'\",\"priority\":\"high\",\"notification\":{\"body\": \"'.stripslashes($message).'\"}}"');
```

Output for result:

**"{"multicast_id":8563984716459935776,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1585669578263131%631c6722f9fd7ecd"}]}"**

But My Application does not recieve push Notification and I could see the send notication in firebase console.
Please Help me for sending and getting Notification using Firebase

Comment: Can you able to receive notification if it is send from firebase console?

Comment: Yes, I receive the notification from firebase cloud messaging console to each device who has install the application.